# Поддержка viewport-fit=cover в chrome на iOS

Tags: html, google-chrome, iphone, media-queries, viewport

Поддерживает ли `viewport-fit=cover` chrome в iOS ?

Нужно исправить отображение на IPhone X в google chrome.

P.S. самого устройства нет под рукой

Comment: https://css-live.ru/articles/ponimanie-vyuporta-webview-v-ios-11.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Появилась возможность протестировать Chrome на IPhone X, сработало!

`viewport-fit=cover` работает.

Comment: Пожалуй, стоит принять ответ.